# Using gratia::draw() in R to display partial effect plots within an HGAM that are not relative to the global smooth

Tags: r, draw, hierarchical-clustering, gam, mgcv

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Lake = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Fork", "TBend"), class = "factor"),
  Depth = c(1.63, 3, 10, 3, 10, 4, 13, 17, 14, 2.81, 20, 3, 28, 24, 6, 
    1.81999999999999, 7, 25, 2.20999999999998, 10, 15, 7.25999999999999, 
    4, 4, 6.64999999999998, 8.83999999999997, 6, 2.20999999999998, 
    22.96, 5.63, 11, 30, 32.31, 25, 1, 3, 4, 7.41000000000003, 2, 
    6, 17, 7, 5, 4.20999999999998, 3, 22, 5, 4.74000000000001, 7, 
    10, 3, 11, 14, 2, 24, 1, 7, 15, 16, 2.68000000000001, 12, 11, 
    5, 10, 10, 6, 12, 4, 4, 4.64999999999998, 18, 7.5, 13, 3, 15, 
    10, 22, 19, 4, 12, 2, 3, 5.41000000000003, 6, 19, 6, 3, 3, 34, 
    3.63, 11, 6, 7, 25, 4, 2.81, 4.70999999999998, 3, 12.31, 5, 17, 
    28, 3.63, 8, 9, 3, 30, 20, 11, 4, 12, 3, 4, 16, 5, 10, 2, 14, 
    58, 10, 2.06, 15, 2.74000000000001, 7, 10.74, 2.81, 11, 6, 5, 
    7.25999999999999, 10, 2.68000000000001, 9, 2.83999999999997, 
    5.5, 15, 7, 6.56, 14, 6, 3.25999999999999, 2.31, 1, 7, 3, 4, 
    2, 3, 9, 28, 18.84, 5, 5, 2.75999999999999, 7.63, 8.20999999999998, 
    18, 3, 11, 1, 24, 4, 22, 2, 3, 4.20999999999998, 14.65, 16, 9, 
    5, 3, 7, 1, 2, 4.5, 2, 20, 1, 10, 17, 4, 2, 1, 23, 5, 11, 12, 
    17, 10, 3, 18, 6, 7, 5, 3, 32, 16, 5, 7, 9, 29, 2, 12, 4, 23, 
    14, 4, 5, 11, 11.82, 6.20999999999998, 7, 12, 3, 6, 4, 17, 4, 
    24, 6, 12, 11.63, 4, 2, 25, 2, 54, 7, 8, 9.25999999999999, 14, 
    15, 11, 6, 21, 1, 3, 8, 1, 2.83999999999997, 19, 6, 19, 2.06, 
    3, 3, 4, 8, 6, 9.41000000000003, 4, 8.64999999999998, 3, 3, 2.5, 
    30, 12, 14, 15, 16, 10.56, 24, 12, 16.71, 25, 1, 10, 17, 1, 1.25999999999999, 
    12, 4, 24, 15, 8.68000000000001, 8, 3, 15.82, 17, 5, 3, 6.70999999999998, 
    5.63, 10, 10.68, 8, 3, 8.81, 5.25999999999999, 22, 12, 5.81999999999999, 
    6, 6, 3.5, 1.52999999999997, 4, 22, 15, 4, 23, 12, 25, 4, 22, 
    5.41000000000003, 9, 19, 8, 4, 8.56, 20, 10.21, 24, 1, 6, 3, 
    10, 3, 28, 12, 6, 17, 1, 3.41000000000003, 6.16000000000003, 
    4, 20.68, 4, 2.74000000000001, 5, 12, 1, 45, 4.74000000000001, 
    18, 15, 1, 8, 20, 21, 3, 16, 1, 3, 30, 10, 6.06, 4, 10.84, 25, 
    26, 12, 2.56, 2, 6, 10.56, 10.31, 16, 29.26, 5, 6, 3.81999999999999, 
    15, 1, 8, 3, 2, 22, 5, 2.95999999999998, 4.5, 1, 18, 2.66000000000003, 
    19, 12, 4, 14, 3, 7, 28, 4, 23, 6, 5, 3, 22, 1, 4, 12, 7, 1.63, 
    12.21, 15, 4, 3, 9, 20.65, 4.74000000000001, 22, 8.81, 5.81999999999999, 
    4.16000000000003, 7, 10, 24, 4.95999999999998, 30, 2, 10, 5, 
    9, 5, 12, 29.82, 2, 6.5, 6.20999999999998, 1, 1, 22, 22, 6.64999999999998, 
    32, 11, 15, 1, 18, 1.81999999999999, 4, 8, 20, 15, 4, 7, 22, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 15, 20, 3, 5, 1.63, 4.66000000000003, 22, 6, 2, 31, 
    20, 5, 9.5, 30, 18, 13, 12, 12, 4.20999999999998, 12, 10.06, 
    2.68000000000001, 2, 1, 5, 2, 9, 2, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2.16000000000003, 
    7, 8.95999999999998, 2.74000000000001, 5, 4, 5, 15, 20, 5.41000000000003, 
    29.41, 7, 32, 4, 14, 2.74000000000001, 4, 15, 8, 21, 32, 13.41, 
    3, 14, 4, 3, 18, 2.31, 25, 3.5, 4.74000000000001, 19, 21, 5.25999999999999, 
    10.21, 12.84, 2.95999999999998, 2, 4.31, 7, 7, 2.31, 17, 10.71, 
    23.41, 3, 3.41000000000003, 4.68000000000001, 22, 3, 13, 15, 
    8.74000000000001, 14.81, 5, 1, 4, 16, 1.41000000000003, 13, 3, 
    2, 6.06, 7, 3, 22, 4.83999999999997, 7, 2.81, 21, 3, 19, 6, 14, 
    2, 1, 10, 7.5, 8.70999999999998, 30, 14, 20, 1, 18, 30, 28, 1.41000000000003, 
    20, 5, 1.41000000000003, 3.5, 4.64999999999998, 5, 9.5, 3, 1.63, 
    11, 21, 2.66000000000003, 20.74, 15, 15, 14, 5, 14, 4.5, 4, 6.06, 
    4.20999999999998, 12, 18, 10.16, 7.81999999999999, 1, 2.95999999999998, 
    15, 2.5, 2.70999999999998, 11, 13.63, 18, 6, 18, 11, 6, 12, 7.5, 
    4.56, 1.38, 2.95999999999998, 17, 4, 1, 15, 4.74000000000001, 
    5.5, 11, 4, 1, 3, 25, 3, 9, 15, 11, 29, 8.56, 23, 14.65, 1, 7, 
    8, 14.06, 2, 3, 26, 2.56, 2.5, 25, 2.74000000000001, 1, 3, 8.56, 
    9.38, 2, 18, 3, 30, 16.96, 4, 22, 11, 6, 4, 3, 8.83999999999997, 
    22, 18, 7, 2.68000000000001, 6, 14.76, 7, 5, 1, 21, 3.81999999999999, 
    10, 3, 5, 7, 6, 20, 6.81, 7, 19, 24, 5, 1, 21.41, 3, 1.81999999999999, 
    10, 11.41, 6, 30, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1.5, 10.5, 18, 10, 2, 25, 14, 4, 
    5.63, 4.20999999999998, 2, 10.84, 10, 7, 30, 1, 17, 3, 3, 22, 
    2.74000000000001, 1, 8, 7, 32.65, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5, 10.76, 
    4, 2, 3.41000000000003, 4, 17),
  OrdDay = c(254, 271, 286, 88, 181, 209, 246, 259, 218, 324, 230, 181, 
    271, 351, 364, 224, 268, 232, 210, 215, 260, 281, 286, 351, 195, 
    167, 248, 54, 308, 254, 322, 125, 33, 248, 336, 319, 322, 238, 
    181, 304, 195, 181, 273, 210, 153, 230, 28, 349, 195, 78, 286, 
    41, 355, 109, 78, 187, 31, 286, 41, 336, 187, 146, 305, 70, 290, 
    129, 290, 160, 83, 195, 147, 7, 159, 195, 146, 195, 181, 11, 
    349, 230, 140, 146, 268, 305, 181, 244, 299, 124, 155, 254, 232, 
    218, 12, 78, 286, 324, 177, 131, 33, 304, 56, 211, 254, 218, 
    60, 167, 147, 167, 322, 181, 299, 167, 215, 351, 230, 334, 25, 
    63, 11, 246, 5, 281, 349, 209, 91, 324, 246, 63, 203, 281, 167, 
    336, 63, 167, 88, 248, 153, 184, 237, 28, 281, 33, 195, 167, 
    109, 260, 56, 268, 248, 259, 187, 11, 124, 75, 254, 54, 218, 
    319, 322, 91, 12, 204, 195, 211, 125, 54, 195, 271, 364, 83, 
    335, 75, 75, 109, 75, 299, 160, 124, 334, 7, 146, 153, 184, 129, 
    146, 181, 131, 364, 31, 124, 11, 304, 290, 181, 204, 195, 322, 
    290, 305, 28, 336, 101, 174, 335, 109, 322, 273, 304, 364, 224, 
    210, 246, 25, 305, 349, 319, 83, 160, 28, 224, 187, 254, 124, 
    7, 167, 195, 12, 12, 187, 281, 101, 336, 304, 195, 244, 75, 232, 
    322, 246, 167, 237, 167, 336, 5, 125, 232, 187, 204, 286, 268, 
    131, 195, 322, 155, 104, 325, 28, 215, 195, 224, 184, 224, 174, 
    177, 167, 21, 363, 244, 268, 281, 286, 286, 335, 286, 336, 286, 
    109, 224, 181, 322, 299, 177, 254, 124, 336, 268, 218, 324, 281, 
    12, 119, 224, 248, 187, 215, 234, 159, 7, 204, 167, 78, 167, 
    325, 244, 290, 238, 305, 322, 246, 334, 184, 195, 210, 335, 160, 
    248, 218, 299, 78, 322, 167, 41, 211, 184, 238, 21, 281, 336, 
    322, 349, 268, 363, 273, 334, 349, 83, 78, 75, 204, 25, 237, 
    104, 232, 195, 319, 363, 355, 5, 335, 167, 237, 349, 286, 184, 
    75, 91, 184, 33, 215, 281, 28, 78, 224, 215, 116, 268, 124, 248, 
    7, 70, 308, 160, 336, 237, 105, 195, 273, 305, 273, 155, 248, 
    281, 160, 209, 259, 63, 101, 143, 67, 187, 203, 11, 254, 210, 
    31, 167, 363, 70, 195, 91, 41, 324, 224, 21, 351, 146, 268, 308, 
    28, 334, 259, 56, 12, 232, 174, 224, 101, 335, 54, 195, 143, 
    25, 171, 195, 167, 336, 281, 203, 25, 224, 75, 218, 248, 160, 
    181, 237, 195, 133, 172, 146, 75, 143, 260, 215, 56, 254, 105, 
    271, 319, 88, 364, 12, 230, 271, 125, 203, 248, 211, 286, 54, 
    63, 5, 336, 259, 105, 28, 299, 224, 172, 125, 75, 299, 177, 105, 
    21, 28, 308, 91, 88, 63, 281, 167, 349, 238, 238, 204, 12, 237, 
    349, 91, 364, 174, 237, 63, 363, 268, 167, 28, 181, 155, 160, 
    33, 304, 244, 349, 248, 28, 281, 54, 167, 308, 116, 33, 224, 
    181, 33, 364, 177, 268, 268, 238, 336, 281, 181, 299, 246, 349, 
    324, 56, 75, 273, 271, 268, 195, 246, 181, 5, 248, 146, 322, 
    167, 140, 324, 286, 286, 174, 322, 60, 187, 260, 335, 104, 177, 
    167, 203, 304, 177, 232, 336, 209, 238, 125, 260, 268, 203, 195, 
    363, 88, 232, 254, 203, 246, 105, 349, 268, 160, 336, 336, 260, 
    88, 56, 5, 54, 363, 31, 21, 224, 260, 308, 355, 25, 177, 167, 
    254, 224, 70, 349, 281, 119, 7, 75, 184, 124, 308, 273, 146, 
    202, 167, 349, 88, 218, 70, 210, 160, 147, 155, 181, 244, 195, 
    56, 184, 41, 195, 160, 260, 101, 5, 116, 230, 351, 184, 25, 224, 
    349, 91, 67, 184, 124, 355, 237, 167, 209, 308, 167, 268, 31, 
    218, 101, 155, 167, 12, 125, 143, 336, 286, 75, 167, 187, 260, 
    304, 224, 203, 290, 125, 195, 290, 355, 324, 153, 187, 349, 355, 
    324, 238, 260, 224, 281, 238, 140, 290, 273, 119, 181, 153, 129, 
    271, 75, 230, 116, 41, 91, 167, 254, 54, 290, 167, 11, 237, 336, 
    105, 181, 11, 286, 244, 349, 91, 230, 336, 195, 119, 230, 349, 
    349, 203, 238, 63, 75, 335, 91, 268, 322, 83),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I am running an HGAM (GI model from Pederson et al. 2019 https://peerj.com/articles/6876/) that looks like this:

```
library(mgcv)
hgam_gi<-gam(Depth~Lake+s(OrdDay,bs="cc")+s(OrdDay,by=Lake,bs='cc')+s(Lake,bs="re"),data=df,family=nb)
```

My partial effect plots look like this:

```
library(gratia)
draw(hgam_gi)
```

[image]

My understanding of these partial effect plots is that the individual smooth LakeTBend doesn't differ much from the global smooth s(OrdDay) thus leadings to no effect in the plot and LakeFork has a stronger effect somewhere around OrdDay 200-250. I am wondering if there's a way to use an HGAM with a global smooth, and extract the individual smooths from that model similar to what you get with an HGAM without a global smooth.

With a model without a global smooth (I model according to Pederson et al. 2019), I can get a better understanding of the individual trends.

```
hgam_i<-gam(Depth~Lake+s(OrdDay,by=Lake,bs='cc'),data=df,family=nb)
draw(hgam_i)
```

[image]

My question is if there is a call I can make in gratia::draw() with an HGAM that can pull the partial effect plots independent of the global smooth? I know I can use predict.gam() to get the the individual predictions for each lake, which is great, but I really like the interpretability of partial effect plots and would love to find a way to run a single parsimonious model that displays global trends and individual trends.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your models are somewhat mis-specified - you have the group (lake) means in the model twice:

1. the parametric `Lake` effect, and
2. the random effect `s(Lake, bs = "re")`

you shouldn't include this effect twice; use one or the other.

Also, your first model really should have something for the `by = Lake` smooths to help the model identify those lake-specific differences from the global smooth. Typically we would add `m = 1` to those `by = Lake` smooths when the model already contains a "global" smooth. You should also set `knots` when fitting a `bs = "cc"` smooth of day (assuming `OrdDay` is day of year?):

```r
library("gratia")
library("mgcv")
library("dplyr")

knots <- list(OrdDay = c(0.5, 366.5))

m <- gam(Depth ~ Lake +
           s(OrdDay, bs = "cc") +
           s(OrdDay, by = Lake, bs = "cc", m = 1),
         data = df, family = nb, knots = knots)
```

another way of specifying this model is using an ordered factor instead of a normal factor. We have to set the contrasts differently so that the parametric term is easier to understand

```r
df <- df |>
  mutate(oLake = ordered(Lake))
contrasts(df$oLake) <- contr.treatment
```

Now when you fit the model we use `oLake` in place of `Lake` and the first smooth of `OrdDay` represents the smooth for the *reference* level of `oLake` (here the reference is: `Fork`). The the `by = oLake` smooth (there is only one here as you only have two levels/lakes) represents the smooth *difference* between the two lakes, such that the smooth for `TBend` is the linear combination of the two smooths in the model

```r
m2 <- gam(Depth ~ oLake +
            s(OrdDay, bs = "cc") +
            s(OrdDay, by = oLake, bs = "cc"),
          data = df, family = nb, knots = knots)
```

With either model, to get estimated smooths for your two lakes, you need to add combinations of smooths. With `m` (the global smooth plus `m = 1` smooths for each lake) we need to form the following combinations:

1. For `Fork` we want `s(OrdDay) + s(OrdDay):LakeFork`
2. For `TBend` we want `s(OrdDay) + s(OrdDay):LakeTBend`

For `m2` where we used ordered factors, we want:

1. For `Fork` we want `s(OrdDay)`
2. For `TBend` we want `s(OrdDay) + s(OrdDay):oLakeTBend`

You can choose to include the group effects or not. Including them would mean you are actually generating fitted values on the response scale which is not what `draw()` shows (it shows partial effects).

To get fitted values we just predict over the range of `OrdDay` for both lakes. Using the development version of {gratia} on GitHub we create a data slice and then use `fitted_values()` on the data slice to yield predicted/fitted values:

```r
ds <- data_slice(m, OrdDay = evenly(OrdDay, n = 100), Lake = evenly(Lake))
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, scale = "response")
fv

library("ggplot2")

fv |>
ggplot(aes(x = OrdDay, y = .fitted, group = Lake)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = .lower_ci, ymax = .upper_ci, fill = Lake), 
    alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Lake))
```

while for `m2` we use

```r
ds2 <- data_slice(m2, OrdDay = evenly(OrdDay, n = 100), oLake = evenly(oLake))
fv2 <- fitted_values(m2, data = ds2, scale = "response")
fv2

library("ggplot2")

fv2 |>
ggplot(aes(x = OrdDay, y = .fitted, group = oLake)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = .lower_ci, ymax = .upper_ci, fill = oLake),
    alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = oLake)) +
  labs(fill = "Lake", colour = "Lake") +
  scale_colour_discrete() +
  scale_fill_discrete()
```

If you don't want the group means, so you are seeing something similar to that `draw()` produces (partial effects), you'll need to currently switch back to `predict.gam()`, using `type = "terms"`, and then sum the rows over the relevant columns:

```r
p <- predict(m2, newdata = ds2, type = "terms")
```

`p` contains

```
r$> head(p)                                                                     
      oLake s(OrdDay) s(OrdDay):oLakeTBend
1 0.0000000 0.2274295           0.00000000
2 0.3846254 0.2274295           0.07137302
3 0.0000000 0.2286423           0.00000000
4 0.3846254 0.2286423           0.07287456
5 0.0000000 0.2263583           0.00000000
6 0.3846254 0.2263583           0.07405621
```

so we only want to sum the rows over columns 2 and 3:

```
fv3 <- rowSums(p[, -1])
```

Getting the standard errors is a bit more difficult in this case, so if including the group means is OK with you, I'll omit the code to get the correct standard errors for the `type = "terms"` idea. Comment if you need that.

#### `"terms"` but with standard errors / credible intervals

If you want the "terms" idea but with standard errors/credible intervals, it's not easy (possible?) to do it directly with `type = "terms"` because we miss the covariances between terms. It is simpler to modify the `fitted_values()` approach (or use `predict.gam()`) to use the `exclude` *or* `terms` arguments to exclude specific terms or include specific terms in the predictions.

For `m` we just want the three smooths (1 global plus the two from the factor by smooth), so we would use:

```r
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, scale = "link",
  terms = c("s(OrdDay)", "s(OrdDay):LakeFork", "s(OrdDay):LakeTBend"))
```

and

```r
fv2 <- fitted_values(m2, data = ds2, scale = "link",
  terms = c("s(OrdDay)", "s(OrdDay):oLakeTBend"))
```

noting that we are now predicting on the link (linear predictor) scale and because we are not using any parametric terms, these smooths are centred about the overall mean, as they would if we'd followed the `"terms"` example, but we get standard errors.

Note that I have updated the code above so that it uses the latest development version of *gratia*, where i have modified quite a few of the variable names. So be sure to install from GitHub, or you'll have to adjust the names for the fitted value (`.fitted` -> `fitted`) and credible interval (`.lower_ci` and `.upper_ci` -> `lower` and `upper` respectively).

#### Alternative way of fitting the GI model

`m` is a GI model, to use the terminology of Pedersen et al (2019). A better way of fitting this model, which wasn't available until recently in mgcv, is through the use of a new basis `"sz"`:

```r
# Alternative GI model
m3 <- gam(Depth ~ s(OrdDay, bs = "cc") +
           s(OrdDay, Lake, bs = "sz", xt = list(bs = "cc")),
         data = df, family = nb, knots = knots)
```

In this model formulation we note:

1. There is no need to specify the parametric factor term for `Lake` as this is actually in the `"sz"` smooth,
2. The first smooth `s(OrdDay)` is the average or global smooth,
   3, The second smooth in the formula is the smooth differences between the global smooth and the individual effects of `OrdDay` in each `Lake`, including the group means,
3. We have to pass the basis we want for the specific smooths, `"cc"` here, through to the constructor using the `xt` argument, because we need to use `bs = "sz"` to specify we want one of these constrained factor smooths,
4. We are using `Lake` here, not `oLake`, so a regular factor,
5. Partial effects plots that combine the global and the individual/group-specific smooths would be created using `fitted_values()` using `exclude` or `terms` as shown below

To get the partial effect plots, we can't now (as far as I know) exclude the difference in group means, but we can produce plots without the model constant term:

```r
fv3 <- fitted_values(m3, data = ds, scale = "link",
  terms = c("s(OrdDay)", "s(OrdDay,Lake)"))

fv3 |>
ggplot(aes(x = OrdDay, y = .fitted, group = Lake)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = .lower_ci, ymax = .upper_ci, fill = Lake), 
    alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Lake))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your extremely thorough response! I love the functionality of the data_slice and fitted values in gratia. I'd love to see how to get standard errors here as partial effect plots are what I am interested in reproducing here. If you can show me how to get the error around those plots, I'd certainly appreciate it!

Comment: Also I am wondering, is m2 the I model and m the GI model? I've been playing around with this and noticing that my outputs are different with the m and m2 models.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering, but if you can show me how to use the type = "terms", I'd be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I would be very interested in the code to get the SEs for the terms, if that's at all possible.

Comment: @srvanderplas I have now added some code for the equivalent; I don't think you can do what you want via "terms" only as we are lacking the covariances between terms. But we can do it via prediction using `fitted_values()` as I show above, but this is also easily done using `predict.gam()` as the `exclude` and `terms` arguments work the same way (`fitted_values()` just passes these arguments on to `predict.gam()`.)

Comment: @DavidSmith Sorry; I must have missed your questions. I have just updated the answer to include code to get partial effect plots for combinations of smooths, using fitted/predicted values rather than via the `"terms"` approach. This comes with standard erros and credible intervals.

Comment: @DavidSmith yes, `m` is a GI and `m2` would be an I in the notation of Pedersen et al. I'll add code for an `m3` which would be a better way of fitting a GI model now than was possible at the time I wrote the original answer, using the "sz" basis.