# Using gratia::fitted_values() to get response predictions for the global smooth in an HGAM

Tags: r, response, predict, gam, mgcv

This question is a follow-up to this post: [Using gratia::draw() in R to display partial effect plots within an HGAM that are not relative to the global smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73807221/using-gratiadraw-in-r-to-display-partial-effect-plots-within-an-hgam-that-ar/73836072#73836072)

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Lake = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                     2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                     1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                     2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                     2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                     2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                     2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                     1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                     2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                     2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                     2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                     2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                     2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                     2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                     2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                     2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                     2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                     2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                     2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                     2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                     2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                     2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                     1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                     2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "T"), class = "factor"),
  D = c(1.63, 3, 10, 3, 10, 4, 13, 17, 14, 2.81, 20, 3, 28, 24, 6, 
            1.81999999999999, 7, 25, 2.20999999999998, 10, 15, 7.25999999999999, 
            4, 4, 6.64999999999998, 8.83999999999997, 6, 2.20999999999998, 
            22.96, 5.63, 11, 30, 32.31, 25, 1, 3, 4, 7.41000000000003, 2, 
            6, 17, 7, 5, 4.20999999999998, 3, 22, 5, 4.74000000000001, 7, 
            10, 3, 11, 14, 2, 24, 1, 7, 15, 16, 2.68000000000001, 12, 11, 
            5, 10, 10, 6, 12, 4, 4, 4.64999999999998, 18, 7.5, 13, 3, 15, 
            10, 22, 19, 4, 12, 2, 3, 5.41000000000003, 6, 19, 6, 3, 3, 34, 
            3.63, 11, 6, 7, 25, 4, 2.81, 4.70999999999998, 3, 12.31, 5, 17, 
            28, 3.63, 8, 9, 3, 30, 20, 11, 4, 12, 3, 4, 16, 5, 10, 2, 14, 
            58, 10, 2.06, 15, 2.74000000000001, 7, 10.74, 2.81, 11, 6, 5, 
            7.25999999999999, 10, 2.68000000000001, 9, 2.83999999999997, 
            5.5, 15, 7, 6.56, 14, 6, 3.25999999999999, 2.31, 1, 7, 3, 4, 
            2, 3, 9, 28, 18.84, 5, 5, 2.75999999999999, 7.63, 8.20999999999998, 
            18, 3, 11, 1, 24, 4, 22, 2, 3, 4.20999999999998, 14.65, 16, 9, 
            5, 3, 7, 1, 2, 4.5, 2, 20, 1, 10, 17, 4, 2, 1, 23, 5, 11, 12, 
            17, 10, 3, 18, 6, 7, 5, 3, 32, 16, 5, 7, 9, 29, 2, 12, 4, 23, 
            14, 4, 5, 11, 11.82, 6.20999999999998, 7, 12, 3, 6, 4, 17, 4, 
            24, 6, 12, 11.63, 4, 2, 25, 2, 54, 7, 8, 9.25999999999999, 14, 
            15, 11, 6, 21, 1, 3, 8, 1, 2.83999999999997, 19, 6, 19, 2.06, 
            3, 3, 4, 8, 6, 9.41000000000003, 4, 8.64999999999998, 3, 3, 2.5, 
            30, 12, 14, 15, 16, 10.56, 24, 12, 16.71, 25, 1, 10, 17, 1, 1.25999999999999, 
            12, 4, 24, 15, 8.68000000000001, 8, 3, 15.82, 17, 5, 3, 6.70999999999998, 
            5.63, 10, 10.68, 8, 3, 8.81, 5.25999999999999, 22, 12, 5.81999999999999, 
            6, 6, 3.5, 1.52999999999997, 4, 22, 15, 4, 23, 12, 25, 4, 22, 
            5.41000000000003, 9, 19, 8, 4, 8.56, 20, 10.21, 24, 1, 6, 3, 
            10, 3, 28, 12, 6, 17, 1, 3.41000000000003, 6.16000000000003, 
            4, 20.68, 4, 2.74000000000001, 5, 12, 1, 45, 4.74000000000001, 
            18, 15, 1, 8, 20, 21, 3, 16, 1, 3, 30, 10, 6.06, 4, 10.84, 25, 
            26, 12, 2.56, 2, 6, 10.56, 10.31, 16, 29.26, 5, 6, 3.81999999999999, 
            15, 1, 8, 3, 2, 22, 5, 2.95999999999998, 4.5, 1, 18, 2.66000000000003, 
            19, 12, 4, 14, 3, 7, 28, 4, 23, 6, 5, 3, 22, 1, 4, 12, 7, 1.63, 
            12.21, 15, 4, 3, 9, 20.65, 4.74000000000001, 22, 8.81, 5.81999999999999, 
            4.16000000000003, 7, 10, 24, 4.95999999999998, 30, 2, 10, 5, 
            9, 5, 12, 29.82, 2, 6.5, 6.20999999999998, 1, 1, 22, 22, 6.64999999999998, 
            32, 11, 15, 1, 18, 1.81999999999999, 4, 8, 20, 15, 4, 7, 22, 
            2, 2, 1, 1, 15, 20, 3, 5, 1.63, 4.66000000000003, 22, 6, 2, 31, 
            20, 5, 9.5, 30, 18, 13, 12, 12, 4.20999999999998, 12, 10.06, 
            2.68000000000001, 2, 1, 5, 2, 9, 2, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2.16000000000003, 
            7, 8.95999999999998, 2.74000000000001, 5, 4, 5, 15, 20, 5.41000000000003, 
            29.41, 7, 32, 4, 14, 2.74000000000001, 4, 15, 8, 21, 32, 13.41, 
            3, 14, 4, 3, 18, 2.31, 25, 3.5, 4.74000000000001, 19, 21, 5.25999999999999, 
            10.21, 12.84, 2.95999999999998, 2, 4.31, 7, 7, 2.31, 17, 10.71, 
            23.41, 3, 3.41000000000003, 4.68000000000001, 22, 3, 13, 15, 
            8.74000000000001, 14.81, 5, 1, 4, 16, 1.41000000000003, 13, 3, 
            2, 6.06, 7, 3, 22, 4.83999999999997, 7, 2.81, 21, 3, 19, 6, 14, 
            2, 1, 10, 7.5, 8.70999999999998, 30, 14, 20, 1, 18, 30, 28, 1.41000000000003, 
            20, 5, 1.41000000000003, 3.5, 4.64999999999998, 5, 9.5, 3, 1.63, 
            11, 21, 2.66000000000003, 20.74, 15, 15, 14, 5, 14, 4.5, 4, 6.06, 
            4.20999999999998, 12, 18, 10.16, 7.81999999999999, 1, 2.95999999999998, 
            15, 2.5, 2.70999999999998, 11, 13.63, 18, 6, 18, 11, 6, 12, 7.5, 
            4.56, 1.38, 2.95999999999998, 17, 4, 1, 15, 4.74000000000001, 
            5.5, 11, 4, 1, 3, 25, 3, 9, 15, 11, 29, 8.56, 23, 14.65, 1, 7, 
            8, 14.06, 2, 3, 26, 2.56, 2.5, 25, 2.74000000000001, 1, 3, 8.56, 
            9.38, 2, 18, 3, 30, 16.96, 4, 22, 11, 6, 4, 3, 8.83999999999997, 
            22, 18, 7, 2.68000000000001, 6, 14.76, 7, 5, 1, 21, 3.81999999999999, 
            10, 3, 5, 7, 6, 20, 6.81, 7, 19, 24, 5, 1, 21.41, 3, 1.81999999999999, 
            10, 11.41, 6, 30, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1.5, 10.5, 18, 10, 2, 25, 14, 4, 
            5.63, 4.20999999999998, 2, 10.84, 10, 7, 30, 1, 17, 3, 3, 22, 
            2.74000000000001, 1, 8, 7, 32.65, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5, 10.76, 
            4, 2, 3.41000000000003, 4, 17),
  OrdDay = c(254, 271, 286, 88, 181, 209, 246, 259, 218, 324, 230, 181, 
             271, 351, 364, 224, 268, 232, 210, 215, 260, 281, 286, 351, 195, 
             167, 248, 54, 308, 254, 322, 125, 33, 248, 336, 319, 322, 238, 
             181, 304, 195, 181, 273, 210, 153, 230, 28, 349, 195, 78, 286, 
             41, 355, 109, 78, 187, 31, 286, 41, 336, 187, 146, 305, 70, 290, 
             129, 290, 160, 83, 195, 147, 7, 159, 195, 146, 195, 181, 11, 
             349, 230, 140, 146, 268, 305, 181, 244, 299, 124, 155, 254, 232, 
             218, 12, 78, 286, 324, 177, 131, 33, 304, 56, 211, 254, 218, 
             60, 167, 147, 167, 322, 181, 299, 167, 215, 351, 230, 334, 25, 
             63, 11, 246, 5, 281, 349, 209, 91, 324, 246, 63, 203, 281, 167, 
             336, 63, 167, 88, 248, 153, 184, 237, 28, 281, 33, 195, 167, 
             109, 260, 56, 268, 248, 259, 187, 11, 124, 75, 254, 54, 218, 
             319, 322, 91, 12, 204, 195, 211, 125, 54, 195, 271, 364, 83, 
             335, 75, 75, 109, 75, 299, 160, 124, 334, 7, 146, 153, 184, 129, 
             146, 181, 131, 364, 31, 124, 11, 304, 290, 181, 204, 195, 322, 
             290, 305, 28, 336, 101, 174, 335, 109, 322, 273, 304, 364, 224, 
             210, 246, 25, 305, 349, 319, 83, 160, 28, 224, 187, 254, 124, 
             7, 167, 195, 12, 12, 187, 281, 101, 336, 304, 195, 244, 75, 232, 
             322, 246, 167, 237, 167, 336, 5, 125, 232, 187, 204, 286, 268, 
             131, 195, 322, 155, 104, 325, 28, 215, 195, 224, 184, 224, 174, 
             177, 167, 21, 363, 244, 268, 281, 286, 286, 335, 286, 336, 286, 
             109, 224, 181, 322, 299, 177, 254, 124, 336, 268, 218, 324, 281, 
             12, 119, 224, 248, 187, 215, 234, 159, 7, 204, 167, 78, 167, 
             325, 244, 290, 238, 305, 322, 246, 334, 184, 195, 210, 335, 160, 
             248, 218, 299, 78, 322, 167, 41, 211, 184, 238, 21, 281, 336, 
             322, 349, 268, 363, 273, 334, 349, 83, 78, 75, 204, 25, 237, 
             104, 232, 195, 319, 363, 355, 5, 335, 167, 237, 349, 286, 184, 
             75, 91, 184, 33, 215, 281, 28, 78, 224, 215, 116, 268, 124, 248, 
             7, 70, 308, 160, 336, 237, 105, 195, 273, 305, 273, 155, 248, 
             281, 160, 209, 259, 63, 101, 143, 67, 187, 203, 11, 254, 210, 
             31, 167, 363, 70, 195, 91, 41, 324, 224, 21, 351, 146, 268, 308, 
             28, 334, 259, 56, 12, 232, 174, 224, 101, 335, 54, 195, 143, 
             25, 171, 195, 167, 336, 281, 203, 25, 224, 75, 218, 248, 160, 
             181, 237, 195, 133, 172, 146, 75, 143, 260, 215, 56, 254, 105, 
             271, 319, 88, 364, 12, 230, 271, 125, 203, 248, 211, 286, 54, 
             63, 5, 336, 259, 105, 28, 299, 224, 172, 125, 75, 299, 177, 105, 
             21, 28, 308, 91, 88, 63, 281, 167, 349, 238, 238, 204, 12, 237, 
             349, 91, 364, 174, 237, 63, 363, 268, 167, 28, 181, 155, 160, 
             33, 304, 244, 349, 248, 28, 281, 54, 167, 308, 116, 33, 224, 
             181, 33, 364, 177, 268, 268, 238, 336, 281, 181, 299, 246, 349, 
             324, 56, 75, 273, 271, 268, 195, 246, 181, 5, 248, 146, 322, 
             167, 140, 324, 286, 286, 174, 322, 60, 187, 260, 335, 104, 177, 
             167, 203, 304, 177, 232, 336, 209, 238, 125, 260, 268, 203, 195, 
             363, 88, 232, 254, 203, 246, 105, 349, 268, 160, 336, 336, 260, 
             88, 56, 5, 54, 363, 31, 21, 224, 260, 308, 355, 25, 177, 167, 
             254, 224, 70, 349, 281, 119, 7, 75, 184, 124, 308, 273, 146, 
             202, 167, 349, 88, 218, 70, 210, 160, 147, 155, 181, 244, 195, 
             56, 184, 41, 195, 160, 260, 101, 5, 116, 230, 351, 184, 25, 224, 
             349, 91, 67, 184, 124, 355, 237, 167, 209, 308, 167, 268, 31, 
             218, 101, 155, 167, 12, 125, 143, 336, 286, 75, 167, 187, 260, 
             304, 224, 203, 290, 125, 195, 290, 355, 324, 153, 187, 349, 355, 
             324, 238, 260, 224, 281, 238, 140, 290, 273, 119, 181, 153, 129, 
             271, 75, 230, 116, 41, 91, 167, 254, 54, 290, 167, 11, 237, 336, 
             105, 181, 11, 286, 244, 349, 91, 230, 336, 195, 119, 230, 349, 
             349, 203, 238, 63, 75, 335, 91, 268, 322, 83),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I am running a GAM that looks like this:

```
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)
knots <- list(OrdDay = c(0.5, 366.5))
m <- gam(D ~ Lake +
           s(OrdDay, bs = "cc") +
           s(OrdDay, by = Lake, bs = "cc", m = 1),
         data = df, family = nb, knots = knots)
```

I am then taking this GAM to get predictions for each lake with the following code.

```
ds <- data_slice(m, OrdDay = evenly(OrdDay, n = 100), Lake = evenly(Lake))

fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, scale = "response")
```

I know I can take the code above and get the individual predicted responses for each lake; however, I am wondering if there is a way to use similar code to get the fitted values for the global term (s(OrdDay)) so that I can get mean predictions for all lakes together?

I've tried troubleshooting to exclude certain terms, but always get predictions for one lake or another using `fitted_values()`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an additive model, so you can select which of the additive terms to include in the fitted values. Note that you'll need the latest CRAN version of {mgcv} to get this to work as prior to this there was some inconsistencies in how `terms` and `exclude` worked in `predict.gam()`.

For your example, it is easiest to just specify the value of `OrdDay` that you want to get fitted values for. `data_slice()` will add on any other variables you need to get passed the checks in `predict.gam()`. So even though, in the data slice below we have a variable `Lake`, we won't use this when actually generating predictions:

```r
ds <- data_slice(m, OrdDay = evenly(OrdDay, n = 100))
fv <- fitted_values(m, data = ds, scale = "response",
                    terms = c("(Intercept)", "s(OrdDay)"))
```

The `terms` argument takes labels as per those shown in the output from `summary(m)`, so here I'm asking for the intercept and the global smooth.

Note however that because of the way R parameterises these models, the intercept is still technically for the refence level of the `Lake` factor.

So perhaps it would be better to fit `Lake` and a random effect so it can be exclude altogether:

```r
m2 <- gam(D ~ s(Lake, bs = "re") +
            s(OrdDay, bs = "cc") +
            s(OrdDay, by = Lake, bs = "cc", m = 1),
          data = df, family = nb, knots = knots)
ds <- data_slice(m2, OrdDay = evenly(OrdDay, n = 100))
fv <- fitted_values(m2, data = ds, scale = "response",
                    terms = c("(Intercept)", "s(OrdDay)"))
```

Then we have

```r
library("ggplot2")

fv |>
ggplot(aes(x = OrdDay, y = fitted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, y = NULL), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Greetings Gavin. I actually tried using all of these functions, but for some odd reason I couldn't find `data_slice`, `fitted_values`, or `evenly` in the `gratia` package. I tried reinstalling the package, but I only see the functions I've seen in the past. Is this something that came with an update? I saw them on the function reference page online but didn't see them on the R help page that lists the package functions.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand You need the development version, see installation instructions on the README in the GitHub repo. This should be on CRAN before the end of the year

Comment: Thanks! Just realized I missed that part of your answer, but anyways this is helpful